# Problem accessing the hyperlink text in a word file (Python-Docx)

Tags: python, cpu-word, python-docx

I have a Big word file that I need to extract data from , this word file contain a lot of tables with data on each cell , I have figured out how to locate the data in the table cells , but some of the data are in form of URLs , is there any way to extract the only the text from the hyperlink

```
this is an example of how I extract the data by providing the row in the table and the Keyword of that Attribute :


| Keyword  |          data             |
| -------- | -------- ---------------- |
| Status   |          Good             |
| Project  | https://www.Google.com    |



def Populate(self,Keyword,row):
        match Keyword:

            case 'Status':
                # print('status')
                self.Status=row.cells[1].text
                print(self.Status)

            case 'Project':
                cell=row.cells[1]                          
                for par in cell.paragraphs :
                    par.clear()
                    self.Project+=par.text
                    for run in par.runs:
                        self.Project+=run.text
                print(self.Project)


the status attribute doesn't contain any Hyperlink , so self.status shall have the text in the cell[1] with no problem 

the project attribute will return empty text because it contains a hyperlink in cell[1]
```